# Leibniz' Rule - Stuck on Problem

Tags: calculus

I am trying hard to learn Leibniz' Rule but am stuck on this:
[image: Leibniz Rule Example]

The source page is [LeibnizRule.pdf](http://www.utdallas.edu/~pervin/ENGR3300/LeibnizRule.pdf)

I don't understand how the answer is apparently gotten by applying Leibniz' Rule, and it does not seem to make sense that the answers (2) are real numbers and not variables.

Can anyone help to explain how the two answers are derived?

Comment: Your question is missing context. What part of the application of the Leibniz rule on the first page of the linked pdf don't you understand? Also, the pdf is missing context too. Why is the limit being taken as $v, u \to 0$?

Comment: You ask "What part of the application...don't you understand?" I don't understand any part of the application.The example in my post is intended to be an application of the Leibniz Rule. I can't see how Leibniz Rule is used at all.

From your comment "Why is the limit being taken to...", I get the idea you feel there are assumptions (context, as you say) missing in the example problem. It seems incompletely stated and solved also to me. Anyone else who does see sense in it? If not, perhaps this question should be dropped as not solvable as stated.